# PhpMyAdmin: "Error in processing request :" (No error shown)

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp, mariadb

I'm running XAMPP on Windows 10 (64-bit) as a development environment. PhpMyAdmin recent started replying to every many attempted actions with the following error - without any actual information about the error. How can I move forward without receiving an error?

[image: error]

Actions that DON'T work:

- Delete row
- Drop table
- Edit row

Actions that DO work:

- View list of tables in a database
- Browse table
- View table structure
- Change details of column in a table's structure view

For context, here is the version info for my PhpMyAdmin:

```
Database server
Server: #.#.#.# via TCP/IP

Server type: MariaDB

Server version: 10.1.13-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution

Protocol version: 10

User: un@host

Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Web server
Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.23

Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: [...] $

PHP extension: mysqli Documentation

PHP version: 5.6.23

phpMyAdmin
Version information: 4.5.1
```

Comment: Run the same command(s) from the mysql commandline tool.  Probably it will be less secretive about the error message.

Comment: I can drop tables without any issue via the command line tool. But there is still the same blank error in phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same symptoms as you, same environment. (which what led me to this question from Google).

I solved it by clearing localhost's data. I believe it had to do with the cookies.

[image: Chrome web developer tools]

Before clearing, I thought my database was corrupted, so I tried to do some drop/update operations using mysql cli. It worked fine. So it was 100% from PhpMyAdmin's side, and in this case, clearing the cookies worked for me.

As for what caused this problem: No idea!

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I remember that there were times that I needed to clear browser storage and cookies for part of my scheme to work. So I'd be surprised if I hadn't tried it. (If so, my b for not saying so.) But since this gig ran it's course and I'm not running the setup anymore, I can't test it to award you the ✔️ - sorry to say!

Comment: No problem! This should serve people coming from Google since searching for 'phpmyadmin error in processing empty' results this page. :)