# Xampp not able to create database nor run a query through Phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp, bitnami

Xampp is working fine. I tried to install SSL locally and made some changes as per some videos but it did not work so I reverted it and now I am not able to create a new database via phpmyadmin nor via php scripts. I dont see any errors as there is no error folder here C:\xampp5633\php. I dont know where else to look for error as apache and mysql are up and running so far no errors there. when I create a new DB it says processing request and hangs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PhpMyAdmin: "Error in processing request :" (No error shown)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43379464/phpmyadmin-error-in-processing-request-no-error-shown)

Comment: I already went through it. still no luck

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48777774/can-not-create-new-database-table-in-xampp-phpmyadmin

Answer (score -1):

in the upper right corner of the phpmyadmin panel click on the icon which have the value of (empty session data)...